# Рассудите спор о запросах и отслеживании браузера

Tags: javascript, ajax, веб-программирование

Есть у меня такой вопрос ,точнее уже не знаю куда пойти  с этим

Мой друг проходит тест на сайте универа и их напугали тем что видят что они открывают другие вкладки браузера.

Я же в свою сторону сказала что у сайтов нету доступа отслеживания действий браузера в этом случае

Уже перерыла все , есть ли такой запрос или нет

Заранее спасибо что потратили свое время

Comment: ну если они пугают такими страшилками, до с образованием все действительно плохо

Comment: а при чем тут есть доступ у сайта или нет? Отслеживать может не сайт, а сам браузер и его расширения. или дядя который смотрит в монитор видеокамеры. хотя надо полагать, счас все тесты проводятся удаленно, а в не в аудиториях.

Comment: если быть параноиком, можно запустить другой браузер и там искать ответы )

Comment: @teran вопрос не в том что кто-то боится или нет , вопрос в том можно ли это сделать (тут больше интерес )

Comment: `<script>
window.onblur = function() {
    alert( 'Не подглядывать!' );
}
</script>